# A new suite of gnu tools for windows

Tags: windows, cygwin, mingw, gnu, gnuwin32

I recently found a new (well RECENT) project that ports gnu tools to windows. Problem is that I can't find it anymore.
It is not gnuwin32, cygwin, [unxutils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UnxUtils), mingw...
I think it is fairly recent and hosted on sourceforge or github and bash is available (I know those indications sucks)

Do anybody have an idea ?

Comment: you say "tools", what do you mean?

Comment: I meant grep/awk/cut/sed/tr... and bash

Comment: @AdamR.Grey, actually it meant to be unx<strong>utils</strong> instead.

Answer (score 1):

I found it back Gow (gnu on windows) [here](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow)